# Циклы внутри цикла. Как оптимизировать?

Tags: python

На вход подается натуральное число n.
Допустим, если  n = 3, то код должен выполнять такую функцию:

```
for i in x:
    print(i)
    for j in x:
        print(j)
        for q in x:
            print(q)
```

Если n = 1, то:

```
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

То есть, если n будет равно, допустим, 50, то таких циклов должно быть 50.
Есть ли способ написать такой код без расписывания минимум ста циклов внутри цикла?

Comment: Можете поконкретнее расписать задачу? Как получаются `i`, `j`, `q`?

Comment: А зачем нужно выполнять такую функцию? Какая цель конечная? Получить повторяющийся вывод одного и того же?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно использовать рекурсию:

```
def recfun(n, x):
    if n:
        for i in x:
            print(i)
            recfun(n-1, x)
```

А можно сделать цикл `for` по значениям `k` от `0 до Q^n-1`, где `Q` - размер `x`, и выводить представление `k` в Q-ричной системе счисления.

А можно так, как электросчётчик работает... Однако рекурсивный код проще всего.

```
def recfun(n, x, s = ""):
    if n:
        for i in x:
            #print(i)
            recfun(n-1, x, s + i)
    else:
        print(s)

recfun(3, "01")
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло, но циклы вашей функции работают только с i, а мне нужно, чтобы с каждым новым циклом буквы менялись. ( i, j, q, w, ...)

Comment: Ух.. На каждом уровне рекурсии будет **новый экземпляр** i, это всё равно, что j, или k или так далее.

Comment: Но если я, допустим, захочу с каждым новым циклом выводить в одну строку значения всех прошлых циклов + значение текущего, то работать это будет некорректно

Comment: передавайте в рекурсивную функцию как аргумент строку или список со "значениями всех прошлых циклов"

Comment: Я имел в виду, что код должен выполнять такую функцию: 
```for i in x: 
    print(i) 
    for j in x: 
        print(i + j) 
        for i in q: 
            print(i + j + q)```

Comment: Вы об этом, может быть, думали, но не спрашивали, а я ответил на заданный вопрос. Однако прошлый комментарий отвечает и на это. Набранную сумму передавайте как параметр функции  `def recfun(n, x, summ=0) ... recfun(n-1, x, summ + i) `

Comment: По моему, ваш вариант не работает, так как при x = 01, а n = 3, должно выводить 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111

Comment: Нет, мой вариант работает. Рабочий код в конце.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Это то, что я хотел. Правда не очень понимаю, как это работает, голова трещит(

Comment: Ну вы понимаете, что конкретно эту задачу проще сделать циклом от 0 до 7, выводя бинарное представление счётчика цикла? Птичка слева - для пометки ответа как решения.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def handle(n):
    for i in x:
        print(i)
    n -= 1
    if n > 0:
        return handle(n)
```

Comment: Даже рядом не похоже.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Я тут подумал насчет вашей идеи, и вот к какому результату я пришел:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

var = {};

def loop(nmb, lst, id = 0):
    if (nmb < 1): pass
    else:
        for var[id] in lst:
            print(var[id]);
            loop(nmb-1, lst, id+1);
    

n = 3;
lst = ["hello", "hi", "greetings"];
loop(n, lst);
```

Вместо того что-бы изменялись переменные (i, j, q, w, ...), я использовал одну переменную, в которой я присваивал свой id, так что получается, в принципе тот-же результат.